# Find points that are 10 ft away from an initial set of GPS points

Tags: javascript, gps

So I have a point [40.894375,-74.172555] and I want to create a border around it.

So what I do is I add a floating number to it which currently is parseFloat("0.00002");
And I generate points that I hope look like what is down at the bottom from it either north,south,east, or west.
But what I get is a list of points that go for multiple miles.

This is an example of what I am looking:

```
                                            ^
                                            |
                                          5-10 ft 
                                            |
               <--- 5-10 ft ---- [40.894375,-74.172555] ---- 5-10 ft --->
                                            |
                                          5-10 ft
                                            |
                                            v
```

does anyone have an idea on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: So why are you adding 0.00002 to the location?

Comment: Do you want to create a square border?

Comment: there is not real reason to the 0.00002 I just wanted a small distance away from the starting point.

And Afsa at the moment it is only really supposed to look like the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have translated a php function ([link](http://www.cosmocode.de/en/blog/gohr/2010-06/29-calculate-a-destination-coordinate-based-on-distance-and-bearing-in-php)) that calculates a GPS point if you give it the start point, the length in km and the bearing.

To find your points use the function

```
geoDestination([40.894375,-74.172555], 0.003048, 0); //Point 10 ft north
geoDestination([40.894375,-74.172555], 0.003048, 90); //Point 10 ft east
geoDestination([40.894375,-74.172555], 0.003048, 180); //Point 10 ft south
geoDestination([40.894375,-74.172555], 0.003048, 270); //Point 10 ft west
```

The translated php function

```
//start is a array [lat, long]
//dist in km
//brng in degrees
function geoDestination(start, dist, brng){
   lat1 = toRad(start[0]);
   lon1 = toRad(start[1]);
   dist = dist/6371.01; //Earth's radius in km
   brng = toRad(brng);

   lat2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(dist) +
              Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(dist)*Math.cos(brng) );
   lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(dist)*Math.cos(lat1),
                      Math.cos(dist)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2));
   lon2 = fmod((lon2+3*Math.PI),(2*Math.PI)) - Math.PI;  

   return [toDeg(lat2),toDeg(lon2)];
}

function toRad(deg){
   return deg * Math.PI / 180;
}

function toDeg(rad){
   return rad * 180 / Math.PI;
}

function fmod(a, b) {
   return Number((a - (Math.floor(a / b) * b)).toPrecision(8));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will check this out when I get a chance.

Comment: I used this function and modified it to give me 30 points to add the accuracy of my border. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One minute of longitude (N<->S) is 1 NM (nautical mile) = 6076.12 ft, thus 10 feet are 0,00164 NM (1/6076.12*10) or 0,00164 of one minute of longitude, or (/60) 2,752e-5  of a degree of longutide. Thus you need to add / subtract 2,752e-5 to/from the longutide to add or subtract 10 feet. This is approx. the number you mentioned in your question.
For the latitude (W<->E) one minute ia 1 NM on the equator, for higher latitudes the distance becomes shorter (by the cosine of the latitude).